# Laravel, multiple belongsto and auto insert ids?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Hello I want to insert a Subboard into board, but this subboard belong to user and board, i'm trying to autoinsert the board id and user id auto but board id aint working this is my code:

Subboard.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Thread;
use App\User;
use App\Board;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subboard extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['subboaName'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'useId' => 'int',
        'boaId' => 'int',
    ];

    /**
     * Obtenemos los threads del board.
     *
     * @return los threads dentro de ese board.
     */
    public function thread()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Thread::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'useId');
    }

    public function board()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Board::class, 'boaId');
    }
}
```

SubboardController.php (the create method)

```
public function subseccion(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'subboaName' => 'required|max:25',
            'boaId' => 'required',
        ]);

        $request->user()->subboards()->create([
            'subboaName' => $request->subboaName,
            'boaId' => $request->boaId,
        ]);

        return redirect('/administrar/subsecciones');
    }
```

Subboards.blade.php (the form where we insert)

```
                                        <form class="form col-md-12 center-block" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/administrar/subsecciones') }}">
                                            {!! csrf_field() !!}

                                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('selectboa') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                                <select name="boaId" class="form-control input-lg selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Selecciona sección" data-style="input-lg btn-default">
                                                    @foreach ($boards as $board)
                                                        <option value="{{$board->id}}">{{$board->boaName}}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                                @if ($errors->has('boaId'))
                                                    <p class="help-block">
                                                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                          <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                                                          {{ $errors->first('boaId') }}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </p>
                                                @endif
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('subboaName') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Nombre de la subsección" name="subboaName" value="{{ old('subboaName') }}">
                                                @if ($errors->has('subboaName'))
                                                    <p class="help-block">
                                                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                          <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                                                          {{ $errors->first('subboaName') }}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </p>
                                                @endif
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">
                                                    Añadir
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add filed names into `$fillable` property

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'subboaName',
    'boaId',
    'useId',
];
```